# Making custom driver for bluetooth in linux

Tags: bluetooth, driver, linux-device-driver

I am having a bluetooth device which  works as a audio reciver. But i want to make it do different thing. I want it to be able to send files. It works like, i have custom driver on sender side which sends file's data to bluetooth device as if it is a audio data. Then the reciver side has custom driver which convert the data stream and convert it to file data.

Is it possible to do so?

And if yes what is the way to start with.

Comment: I don't think anyone will help ya. Will upvote and advice: linux OS is opensource project. This way it is possible to find sources of drivers, programs, etc. It seems that it is the only way

Comment: Have you read Bluetooth specification? Why not?

Comment: You have marked this as a Linux, so is there any reason you cannot use OBEX to exchange the data? E.G. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/119818/121848

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, file transfer via Blutooth is already possible. Look for `obexftp`.

Comment: Not all profiles support that, AFAIU the device in question is for A2D profile only. https://www.nfon.com/en/service/knowledge-base/knowledge-base-detail/a2dp So I don’t think you answered the question while the question itself is a bit foggy.

Comment: I agree that the question is not very clearly worded as far as the topic is concerned, but the heading and the tags, on the other hand, are very clear about Linux and Bluetooth. And in this case, `obexftp` is the answer when it comes to file transfer via Bluetooth.

Comment: Read about Bluetooth profiles, you are not answering the question, really.